# Global menu stopped working for most applications

Tags: unity, appmenu

I have Ubuntu 12.04 32 bits and I had been enjoying  global menus and HUD since the beginning. However, for some strange reason, I stopped having global menus for most applications and thus no HUD fun anymore. Actually, the only two applications where I continue to have global menus are Thunderbird and Firefox, so not sure if it has something to do with these two...

I've already browsed through some similar reports and already tried the following:

1. checking if indicator-appmenu was installed.
2. tried to use Unsettings to switch on and off, with reboots in the middle, global menus.
3. logged in with a different user to see if it was some configuration of my user.
4. also checked, using dconf-editor that, com → canonical → indicator → appmenu → menu-mode = "global"

Any hint/help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).